# LUA: count occurrences of a character into a string?

Tags: lua

How can I count the occurrences of a specific character into a string, with LUA, please?

I give here an example

let the string: "my|fisrt|string|hello"

I want to count how many occurrences of the character "|" has the string.
In this case, it should return 3

How can I do it please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simple solution is just to count it character by character:

```lua
local count = 0
local string = "my|fisrt|string|hello"
for i=1, #string do
    if string:sub(i, i) == "|" then
        count = count + 1
    end
end
```

Alternatively, count all the matches for your character:

```lua
local count = 0
local string = "my|fisrt|string|hello"
for i in string:gmatch("|") do
    count = count + 1
end
```

Comment: I was about to post an answer using `gsub` instead of `gmatch` (increasing the counter in the callback), but you beat me to it, so... take my upvote.

Comment: I made a small error in `gmatch` anyway. I thought it would split by the character instead of matching the character, so my counting was off. Quickly caught it and fixed it luckily

Comment: I successfully employed the second example you've suggested. Thank you so much

Comment: @HenrikIlgen you don't have to increase a counter in gsub's callback. gsub already returns the number of replacements done

Answer (score 6):

`gsub` returns the number of operations in the second value

```
local s = "my|fisrt|string|hello"

local _, c = s:gsub("|","")
print(c) -- 3
```